# self.close() will close the program even though closeEvent() has self.ignore() inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

when i click 'X' on my application, and press "No" from MessageBox, the program **will not be closed**. But when i hide the program and click "Quit" from the Menu at system tray and click "No" from the MessageBox, the program **will still be closed** successfully....

my code is something like this:

```
    exitAction = menu.addAction("Quit")
    exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
```

then my closeEvent() code is:

```
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Quit', 'Are You Sure to Quit?', QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Yes)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

EDIT:
I realised whenever the menu pops up an QMessageBox, no matter which option i choose, the whole program will still be closed, i think it might be this problem?:

```
os._exit(app2.exec_())
```

i added **self.show()** before the messagebox and it works, is there any way to make it works without self.show()? Because i am allowing user to quit the program from system tray when the program is hidden

```
   def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.show() << I added this and it works
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Quit', 'Are You Sure to Quit?', QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Yes)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

Reproducible Code:

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.resize(350, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        pb_min = QPushButton("Minimise the Program", self)
        pb_min.clicked.connect(self.pbMin)

        h_box = QHBoxLayout()
        h_box.addStretch()

        h_box.addWidget(pb_min)
        h_box.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(h_box)

    def pbMin(self):
        menu = QMenu()
        showAction = menu.addAction('Show')
        showAction.triggered.connect(self.showGUI)
        exitAction = menu.addAction("Quit")
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.hide()
        self.mSysTrayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        icon = QIcon("test.png")
        self.mSysTrayIcon.setIcon(icon)
        self.mSysTrayIcon.setContextMenu(menu)
        self.mSysTrayIcon.setToolTip("Show Test")
        self.mSysTrayIcon.activated.connect(self.onActivated)
        self.mSysTrayIcon.show()

    def showGUI(self):
        self.show()
        self.mSysTrayIcon.hide()

    def onActivated(self, reason):
        if reason == self.mSysTrayIcon.Trigger:
            self.show()
            self.mSysTrayIcon.hide()


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Quit', 'Are You Sure to Quit?', QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    os._exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Is there any chance that it's MacOS?

Comment: @musicamante I am using Windows 10

Comment: Ok, I see your edit, now it's a bit more clear. A couple of questions: by "Quit from the Menu at system tray", you mean that you're using a QSystemTrayIcon, or that you are clicking on "Close Window" in the taskbar?

Comment: @DanielSeow provide a [MRE]

Comment: @musicamante quit from QSystemTrayIcon

Comment: @DanielSeow if that's the case, you should be clear if you're actually hiding (via `hide()`) when you say that you're "hiding" the window, because that's not clear at all from your answer. As @eyllanesc said, you should really edit your question and provide us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can better understand how you're dealing with events, since "close", "hide" and "quit" are **very** different things, expecially when relating to system tray icons. We cannot just guess if you don't exactly tell us what you actually do.

Comment: @musicamante sorry for not providing it earlier, I've provided it now

Comment: @DanielSeow If you have found the solution then write an answer explaining the solution, do not do it in your question since it will not serve the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with the code you provided.

First of all, you shouldn't create a new system tray icon everytime you minimize the window; while it *might* make *some* sense, it can be a problem as in some platforms (notably, Windows) the icon might not always be "deleted" (as in "hidden") when you create a new one, unless you explicitly delete it (usually with `deleteLater()`).

Then, while you say that "the program will still be closed successfully", it's possible that it won't. That usually depends on the platform (different OSes and OS versions), but that's not the point.

Also, since you need a unified way to ensure that the user *really* wants to quit, you should provide a respective method to do that, and therefore react to its return value, since `closeEvent` and triggered action connections respond in different ways.

I've adapted your code, unifying a "closeRequest" method that should better react to user interaction.

A couple of notes.

1. Whenever you're using "non standard" QWidgets (such as QSystemTrayIcon) you will need better control on how/when your program actually quits, and special care is required in setting [`QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(bool)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop).
2. Using `os._exit` is **not** the same as `sys.exit`: "`os._exit()` should normally only be used in the child process after a fork()", which is the (rarely) case of concurrent event loops, such as using PyQt event loop along with a PyGame one (see [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit)).

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.resize(350, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        pb_min = QPushButton("Minimise the Program", self)
        pb_min.clicked.connect(self.pbMin)

        h_box = QHBoxLayout()
        h_box.addStretch()

        h_box.addWidget(pb_min)
        h_box.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(h_box)

        menu = QMenu()
        showAction = menu.addAction('Show')
        showAction.triggered.connect(self.showGUI)
        exitAction = menu.addAction("Quit")
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.quitRequest)
        self.mSysTrayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        icon = QIcon("test.png")
        self.mSysTrayIcon.setIcon(icon)
        self.mSysTrayIcon.setContextMenu(menu)
        self.mSysTrayIcon.setToolTip("Show Test")
        self.mSysTrayIcon.activated.connect(self.onActivated)

    def pbMin(self):
        self.hide()
        self.mSysTrayIcon.show()

    def showGUI(self):
        self.show()
        self.mSysTrayIcon.hide()

    def onActivated(self, reason):
        if reason == self.mSysTrayIcon.Trigger:
            self.show()
            self.mSysTrayIcon.hide()

    def quitRequest(self):
        if self.closeRequest():
            QApplication.quit()

    def closeRequest(self):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Quit', 'Are You Sure to Quit?', QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        return reply == QMessageBox.Yes

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.closeRequest():
            event.accept()
            QApplication.quit()
        else:
            event.ignore()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: With your code, i tried only creating the system tray when the program is running at the beginning. But the system tray is shown when I run the program

Comment: Well, it shouldn't, but QSystemTrayIcon is known as having erratic behavior across systems and Qt versions. Have you tried to hide it, once it's created?

Comment: @DanielSeow are you using your code or mine? Because, as explained in my answer, continuously creating new instancies of a QSystemTrayIcon will not result in hiding previous ones in most cases. If that's not the case, please try to better explain your efforts, possibly by improving your question or describe them here in the comments; I know that's hard to do, but that's how things are done here, and for very good reasons.

Comment: yes, i am using your code, when i run it, the QSystemTrayIcon is shown in the system tray at the beginning. So i added self.mSysTrayIcon.hide() after         self.mSysTrayIcon.activated.connect(self.onActivated) but the system tray icon is still showing

Comment: Are you sure you're not creating the QSystemTrayIcon more than once? Where/how do you hide it? And are you sure you're not showing it anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution, whenever the main program is hidden, messagebox shown through system tray once is closed, the whole program will shut down as well,
so add `app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)` to avoid the closing of MessageBox leading to the whole program to shut down. 
Lastly, add `quit()` in the closeEvent()